# OWASP ZAP Authentication - can't stop it using zap/zap

Tags: owasp, zap

I can't get zap past the login page. It just fixates on the login and forgotten password forms.

I have followed various official HOWTOs and this [FAQ](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth) but even though I have deleted the `zap` user, it still uses `login_id=ZAP&password=ZAP` when trying to log in.

I'm in standard mode, forced user mode, forced user is defined, logged in and logged out strings are defined - and I have tried others.

login form target url: `https://xxx.yyy.net/affiliate_login_action.ido`

login request POST data: `login_id={%username%}&password={%password%}`

logged in regex: `\QLogout\E`

logged out regex: `\QAgent Login\E`

I can't think what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

The regexs doesn't seem right. In my experience when you don't specify correct login/logout regexs ZAP is using just `ZAP`, `ZAP`.

Try to change regexs to `.*\QLogout\E.*` and `.*\QAgent Login\E.*`